# DOMXPath get sibling depending on previous sibling value

Tags: php, xml, dom, domxpath

Let's say I have this:

```
<foo>
    <bar>CCC</bar>
    <baz>sometexthere</baz>
</foo>
<foo>
    <bar>AAA</bar>
    <baz>sometext</baz>
</foo>
<foo>
    <bar>DDD</bar>
    <baz>something</baz>
</foo>
```

Now, I want to get the **baz** value, which is coming right after **bar** with the value **AAA** (!but only with the value **AAA**!). I don't know how many "foo"s I have, so I can't exactly write something like:

```
$element->item(0) // I don't know the exact number
```

So how can I get the value of the baz, which follows after bar with a particular value?

(For the example above, I would like to get **sometext** because it comes after **AAA**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic query would be to find the `bar`s that contain `AAA`, then navigate to the corresponding `baz` element.

```
//foo/bar[.="AAA"]/../baz
```

Or, find all `baz` and filter based on the associated `bar`.

```
//foo/baz[../bar = "AAA"]
```

Or, `baz`s within `foo`s containing `bar` having `AAA`.

```
//foo[bar="AAA"]/baz
```

If you're not familiar with XPath expressions, bookmark [XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for later.

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways to write a matching XPath depending on exactly how you want the match to be performed. Here are some options:

Find a baz where there's also a `<bar>AAA</bar>`, not necessarily preceding it though (it could come after, or there could be other elements in between):

```
foo[bar = 'AAA']/baz
```

Find a baz preceded by `<bar>AAA</bar>`:

```
foo/baz[preceding-sibling::bar = 'AAA']
foo/bar[. = 'AAA']/following-sibling::baz
```

Find a baz **immediately** preceded by `<bar>AAA</bar>`:

```
foo/baz[preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::bar = 'AAA']
foo/bar[. = 'AAA']/following-sibling::*[1]/self::baz
```

Find a `<bar>AAA</bar>` and return whatever element comes immediately after it, not necessarily named baz.

```
foo/bar[. = 'AAA']/following-sibling::*[1]
```